# What happens to indexes when the type of a column is changed in a H2 database?

Tags: h2

I just noticed that there is no error when I run a statement like

```
ALTER TABLE <tableName> ALTER column <columnName> <newType> [...]
```

in an H2 database. But if there is an index (or more) on that column, what happens to it/them? Do they get automatically adjusted? Are they just lost?

Thank you!

Comment: What happened when you tried?